# Custom field annotation to validate values from excel through bean in Java

Tags: java, spring-annotations

I'm working on a Java project where I need to validate field values using custom annotations and read data from an Excel file for validation purposes. However, I've encountered challenges in implementing this. Here's the relevant code and explanation of what I'm trying to achieve:

I have a Java class called ExcelBean with fields annotated using a custom annotation `@ExcelField`. Here's a snippet of the `ExcelBean` class:
Also I want to format the date as per my specified format using annotation. Can anyone please suggest me , how can I do? I am unable to get values inside annotation.

I have used the annotation here in the bean:

```java
public class ExcelBean {

@ExcelField(excelColumn = "ID")
private String id;

@ExcelField(excelColumn = "NAME")
private String name;

@ExcelField(excelColumn = "EMAIL", emailFormat = true, required = true)
private String email;

@ExcelField(excelColumn = "BIRTHDATE", dateFormat = "dd-MM-yyyy")
private String birthDate;

@ExcelField(excelColumn = "FEES", decimalFormat = true)
private String fees;

@ExcelField(excelColumn = "LOCATION", decimalFormat = true)
private String location;
}
```

I also have a custom validator class `ExcelFieldValidator` that implements the `ConstraintValidator` interface to perform validation based on the `@ExcelField` annotations. Here's a snippet of the `ExcelFieldValidator` class:

```java
public class ExcelFieldValidator implements ConstraintValidator<ExcelField, String> {

private ExcelField excelField;

@Override
public void initialize(ExcelField excelField) {
    this.excelField = excelField;
}

@Override
public boolean isValid(String value, ConstraintValidatorContext context) {

    if (value == null) {
        return false;
    }

    if (excelField.required() && value.trim().isEmpty()) {
        return false;
    }

    String expectedColumnName = excelField.excelColumn();

    // Verify that the excelColumn attribute is not empty
    if (expectedColumnName.isEmpty()) {
        return false;
    }

    // Replace spaces and make the column name case-insensitive for comparison
    expectedColumnName = expectedColumnName.replaceAll("\\s", "").toLowerCase();

    // Get the actual column name from the Excel file (you will need to implement
    // this)
// List columnNames = getActualColumnNameFromExcelFile();

// String actualColumnName = columnNames.contains();

    // Compare the expected and actual column names
// if (!expectedColumnName.equals(actualColumnName.toLowerCase())) { // return false; // }

    if (!value.isEmpty() && value.length() < excelField.minLength())

    {
        return false;
    }

    if (value.length() > excelField.maxLength()) {
        return false;
    }

    if (excelField.emailFormat() && !isValidEmail(value)) {
        return false;
    }

    if (excelField.decimalFormat() && !isValidDecimal(value)) {
        return false;
    }

    if (!excelField.dateFormat().isEmpty()) {
        if (!isValidDate(value, excelField.dateFormat())) {
            return false; // Date format is not valid
        }
    }

    return true; // All validation checks passed
}

private boolean isValidEmail(String email) {
    if (email == null || email.isEmpty()) {
        return false;
    }

    String regex = "^[A-Za-z0-9+_.-]+@(.+)$";

    return email.matches(regex);
}

private boolean isValidDecimal(String decimal) {
    if (decimal == null || decimal.isEmpty()) {
        return false; // Decimal cannot be null or empty
    }

    try {
        Double.parseDouble(decimal);
        return true;
    } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
        return false; // Parsing as a decimal failed
    }
}

private boolean isValidDate(String date, String dateFormat) {
    if (date == null || date.isEmpty()) {
        return false;
    }

    try {
        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat(dateFormat);
        sdf.setLenient(false);
        sdf.parse(date);
        return true;
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        return false; // Parsing as a date failed
    }
}
```

**My goal is to :**

Read data from an Excel file and compare it with the excelColumn attribute in the `@ExcelField` annotations.
Perform various validations, such as checking for required fields, minimum and maximum length, email format, decimal format, and date format.
I am unable to find solution for how my annotations can read the data in my excel column.